# Correlated Update

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm trying to update one table using fields from another:

```
Update x
From y
Set 1=y.1, 2=y.2, 3=y.3
Where y.4="*Cash*" and y.5="*Use*"
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to use an Inner Join or a Subquery? I keep getting an error in my Update Syntax: "Missing or Invalid Option."

Comment: What are these fields `1`, `2`, `3`, `y.4` and `y.5`? Are you referring to their position, or are these actual field names? Are you going to update every row in `x`, or just some rows that match some condition?

Comment: y.1, y.2, y.3, y.4, and y.5 are columns in table y. I would like to update every row in x with every matching field in y.1, y.2, and y.3 which match y.4 with cash in the string and y.5 with use in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking for something like

```
UPDATE x
   SET (col1, col2, col3) = (select y.col1, y.col2, y.col3
                               from y
                              where y.col4 = '*Cash*'
                                and y.col5 = '*Use*')
```

Normally, there would be some additional condition that relates the tables `x` and `y`.  If the query against `y` returns a single row and you want to update every row of `x` with that single row of data, that is not necessary.  But normally, you'd have something like

```
UPDATE x
   SET (col1, col2, col3) = (select y.col1, y.col2, y.col3
                               from y
                              where y.col4 = '*Cash*'
                                and y.col5 = '*Use*'
                                and x.someKey = y.someKey)
```

If you only want to update the rows in `x` that have a matching row in `y`

```
UPDATE x
   SET (col1, col2, col3) = (select y.col1, y.col2, y.col3
                               from y
                              where y.col4 = '*Cash*'
                                and y.col5 = '*Use*'
                                and x.someKey = y.someKey)
 WHERE EXISTS( select 1
                 from y
                where y.col4 = '*Cash*'
                  and y.col5 = '*Use*'
                  and x.someKey = y.someKey)
```